# `KernelMixtureDistribution` error message about precision

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, distributions, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I want to use `KernelMixtureDistribution` to deal with a large amount of data points. For example, the following codes shows how I use it:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 2}];
d1 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, MaxMixtureKernels -> All]
ContourPlot[PDF[d1, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 20]
```

and it works fine. However, I want to specify the bandwidth manually, like this:

```
d2 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, 0.01, MaxMixtureKernels -> All]
ContourPlot[PDF[d2, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 20]
```

then it gives me a lot of error message and gets stuck:

[image: Error message]

To specify a bandwidth manually is important for me. So my question is: how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With even a moderate sample size you're going to get pretty much the same resulting contour plot no matter what kernel type you use (even if the kernel is the `"Rectangular"` kernel).  So avoid the `"Gaussian"` kernel for large sample sizes and you won't see those warning messages.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 2}];
d2 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, 0.01, "Epanechnikov", MaxMixtureKernels -> All];
ContourPlot[PDF[d2, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 20]
```

[image: Contour plot of kernel density]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 2}];
```

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to investigate changes in the bandwidth and/or [`MaxMixtureKernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxMixtureKernels.html).

```
Manipulate[
 d2 = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, bw,
   MaxMixtureKernels -> mmk];
 cp = ContourPlot[
   PDF[d2, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> All,
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
   Contours -> 20,
   ImageSize -> 324,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15],
 Row[{Control[{{bw, 0.05, "bandwidth"}, 0.01, 0.2, 0.01, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled",
     ImageSize -> Small}],
   Spacer[15],
   Control[{{mmk, All, "MaxMixtureKernels"}, {Automatic, All, 10, 15, 
      20}}]}],
 TrackedSymbols -> True,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

As stated in the error messages, when the bandwidth is made too small some of the exponential terms cannot be represented. Specifying a `WorkingPrecision` helps some, but this slows down the calculations.